# Why does my prettier remove the ABIEncoderV2?

Tags: solidity

I'm using prettier to lint and fix my formatting of .sol files.

But for some reason, anytime it encounters `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`, it transforms it to `pragma experimental ;`.

Why's it doing this?

My `.prettierrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  overrides: [
    {
      files: "*.sol",
      options: {
        bracketSpacing: false,
        printWidth: 145,
        tabWidth: 4,
        useTabs: false,
        singleQuote: false,
        explicitTypes: "always",
      },
    },
    {
      files: "*.ts",
      options: {
        printWidth: 145,
        semi: false,
        trailingComma: "es5",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: What command are you actually running to apply those formatting rules? Also, do you have prettier-plugin-solidity installed?

Comment: Yes it's installed and I'm running `npx prettier --write Contract.sol`

Comment: Nvm it turns out I needed to upgrade `prettier-plugin-solidity`